# iPhone Parsing Enclosure url tag?

Tags: iphone, rss, xml-parsing, gdata

I am having an issue with a blog I am working on.  The method I am using to parse is:

```
NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels)
{
    NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];
    NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items)
    {
        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
    }
}
```

EDIT:  XML LOOKS LIKE:

```
<item>
    <title>Your Direction Determines Your Destination</title>
    <link>http://treymorgan.podbean.com/2012/06/05/your-direction-determines-your-destination/</link>

    <comments>http://treymorgan.podbean.com/2012/06/05/your-direction-determines-your-destination/#comments</comments>
    <pubDate>Tue, 05 Jun 2012 17:57:07 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>treymorgan</dc:creator>

<category></category>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://treymorgan.podbean.com/2012/06/05/your-direction-determines-your-destination/</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[Part 1 of the series &#8230; Road Trip

]]></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Part 1 of the series &#8230; Road Trip
</p>
]]></content:encoded>

        <wfw:commentRss>http://treymorgan.podbean.com/2012/06/05/your-direction-determines-your-destination/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
        <enclosure url="http://treymorgan.podbean.com/mf/feed/x52488/DirectionDeterminesyourDestination.mp3" length="32015229" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</item>
```

This way I can get the title of the article from the Title tag within the XML.  Most xmls I have parsed have included the mp3, either in the "guid" or "link" tag.  However, the current feed I am working with, looks like this:

```
<enclosure url="http://treymorgan.podbean.com/mf/feed/bf8mvq/Accommoditions.mp3" length="29865594" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

How can I pass the url from the enclosure into an NSString?

Comment: how does the xml look like? I mean where is this enclosure written, where does this string is in the xml/file/server-string? simply: how's the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `[[item attributeForName: @"url"] stringValue]` should do it. Depending on the actual location of the `enclosure` element in the XML tree, you might need to use another element instead of `channel` of course.

Answer is

```
[[[[item elementsForName: @"enclosure"] lastObject] attributeForName: @"url"] stringValue]
```

Comment: Then it would be `[[[[item elementsForName: @"enclosure"] lastObject] attributeForName: @"url"] stringValue]`